# How do I create a wait event in dojo that waits for a user to click a button before continuing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, button, dojo

I have the following code in a javascript file:

```
if(dojo.byId('WC_selectedColorNumber') == null && this.defaultColor != null)
{   
    dijit.byId('WC_color_selection').domNode.style.display = 'block';
    dojo.html.set(dojo.query(".message__button .add"), "Add product with only base color " + this.defaultColor + "?");

    var userResponse = true;

    dojo.connect(WC_add_color_yes, "onclick", function(evt){
        userResponse = true;
    });

    dojo.connect(WC_add_color_no, "onclick", function(evt){
        userResponse = false;
    });

    //var userResponse = confirm("Add product with only base color " + this.defaultColor + "?");

    //I WANT TO WAIT HERE FOR THE RESPONSE

    if(userResponse == false) //if user clicks Cancel or 'no', display a message and leave the function.
    {
        alert("Remember to select a color before adding to cart."); //should be a tooltip/popup (not javascript alert) with the same message
        return; //return so item doesn't get added to cart
    }
}
```

Firstly, the logic behind this code is correct and it works perfectly well when using javascript confirm's.

As of now, everything comes up and displays correctly, and clicking the buttons perform the correct actions (if I put a console.log in the onclick dojo events, they do indeed print to the console when I click the buttons).  However, the program doesn't wait for the responses and continues beyond the dojo.connect methods before it sees the user's input.

I need it to wait until either the yes or no button have been pressed, but I cannot figure out how to do it.  I've tried using a

```
while(userResponse == null);
```

but a) it's generally a terrible idea and b) it didn't work anyways.

How can I make my code wait until the user has clicked one of the two buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a jsfiddle I'd be able to help you more, I think, but your `dojo.connect` calls shouldn't be inside a logic flow like this. Instead, set up your connects on widget `startup`, and have them act generically.

In your example code, it looks to me like saying "Yes" means "Use default color", and "No" means "User must specify color". So...

```
startup: function () {
    this.inherited(arguments);

    dojo.connect(WC_add_color_yes, "onclick", dojo.hitch(this, function(evt){
        this.useDefaultColor();
    }));

    dojo.connect(WC_add_color_no, "onclick", dojo.hitch(this, function(evt){
        this.displayColorPicker();
    }));
}
```

And then... only display those two buttons (or the dialog they're hopefully in) when applicable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "wait" or "sleep" function in javascript and each invocation of javascript code executes to completion (it does not get interrupted in mid execution by a response to some other event). You have correcly identified the historical execeptions that overcome this - global alert and confirm functions execute in browser native code and wait on user input.

Because of this your code will have to be restructured in some way, e.g. an event handler for "add to cart" validates the color choice and calls a function to really add it to the cart if valid. If it is not valid it modifies the DOM to present user with some buttons. The handler for the "yes" option would likewise call the same function to really add it to the cart.

Specific code is outside the scope of this answer - there must be many methods in page and code design to achieve the desired result. For example only: breaking up the  sequential code and putting it in separate event handlers, coding using Promise objects defined in EC6 but not supported in MSIE, or perhaps even providing an option of "none - base color only" in the color selection logic.

FYI the dojo 1.10 toolkit documentation reports support for Dojo Promises but I leave research to determine its suitability with you.